# Selecting the text a given range in a textarea (as if the user was holding down shift and arrows)

Tags: jquery, html

Update: I am sorry for not making it clear - i do not mean getting the text, i meant emulate the effect as if the user had double-clicked on a word in the text area.

Supposed i have a textarea that looks like this:

```
<textarea id="r">Hello, this is random text. i want to select -> THIS </textarea>
```

I want to select the last 4 characters of this textarea, preferably w jQuery

How do i do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
$('#r').val().substr(-4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/nc4pk/

Comment: Way more elegant solution. Only thing I suggest is trimming the data, because he says the last 4 characters, and I think by error has the extra space. +1

Comment: Heres an updated with space trimming so it always gets the last 4 characters. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/nc4pk/1/

Comment: Thanks. I think our answer is not what he wants. He want to highlight the text, not just get the text.